# (Simplified) SQL translator for MongoDB?

Tags: sql, mongodb, unql

Is there an automated script that can translate SQL-like queries to MongoDB queries?  Even if it's just things like:

FROM table SELECT a, b, SUM(c) as my_sum WHERE d > 4?

Or maybe an automated UnQL to MongoDB translator?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this website [querymongo.com](http://www.querymongo.com/) it does exactly what you want/need.

Answer (score 0):

Not currently that I've seen.. however I have two suggestions on the matter:

- Could create a Github project to do this and see if the community as a collective whole could put one together.
- Use this link: [SQL to Mongo Mapping](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/SQL+to+Mongo+Mapping+Chart) from Mongo which already has everything in it ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most recent (on-going) effort at offering SQL-to-mongo translation is coming from Keith Schnable's interface at http://mongosql.com

Gary R.

Comment: Yes me too. The site is unavailable.